# how to combine after insert with instead of insert trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an instead of update trigger that evaluates a condition before firing, and at the end of the trigger, i'd like to fire an after update trigger which performs a simple query. However, I'm not sure if an after trigger is the correct solution, and, in any case, my clumsy attempt to include the after trigger at the end results in numerous syntax errors.

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE SHAPE IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN 
INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid, loc_name) 
SELECT SHAPE, X_Coord = SHAPE.STX,Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY,objectid, loc_name 
FROM inserted; 
END

ELSE 
BEGIN 
INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid,loc_name) 
SELECT SHAPE=Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('
+ CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' 
+ CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917),
X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid,loc_name
FROM inserted;
END

END
go

after insert 
as 
begin
set nocount on;
    INSERT INTO TBL_LOCATIONS (TOPO_NAME) 
    SELECT dbo.QD24K_GRSM.NAME 
    FROM   INSERTED I 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.QD24K_GRSM 
    on QD24K_GRSM.Shape.STContains(I.SHAPE) = 1;
    go
```

Accepted answer, modified to handle additional cases, I'm sure I'm not the only one whom can benefit from this example:

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT  
AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 --insert binary xy to geo column when user enters location from non-gis app (a);
 --insert topo quad (b) name and county (c) name admin boundary which location occurs
  INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid, loc_name, TOPO_NAME, County)  
  SELECT a.Shape, a.X_Coord, a.Y_Coord, a.objectid, a.loc_name, b.NAME, c.name
  FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT 
    --see if GIS populated geo column, if not, write user-input xy to geometry 
      SHAPE = CASE WHEN SHAPE IS NOT NULL  
        THEN SHAPE ELSE Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(' 
          + CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' '  
          + CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917) END, 
    --if record was created with GIS, then translate binary to human-readable xy
      X_Coord = CASE WHEN SHAPE IS NULL THEN X_Coord ELSE SHAPE.STX END, 
      Y_Coord = CASE WHEN SHAPE IS NULL THEN Y_Coord ELSE SHAPE.STY END, 
      objectid,  
      loc_name 
    FROM inserted 
  ) AS a
  --spatial query, what topo quad is this point in?
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QD24K_GRSM AS b 
      ON b.Shape.STContains(a.Shape) = 1 
   --spatial query, what county is this point in?
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.COUNTY as c 
      ON c.Shape.STContains(a.Shape) = 1; 
END 
GO 
GO
```

Aaron is right, this will not handle update situations where the user alters the xy column and/or uses the GIS application to move the point, HOWEVER, at least it doesn't crash when that situation occurs, either. I supposed an after-update trigger would handle that, but at this stage, it is the role of the application manager to keep track of the rare point edits after they're inserted. If user supplied X or Y is null, then the geometry will be null,and periodic DB maintence will cull those records, and move them to a temp table where the location is somewhere in the atlantic, for manual location determination.

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` is a pseudo-table, that can contain multiple rows. As such, performing an `IF EXISTS` test against it tells you, at most, the status of a *single* row.

Comment: @Damien yes, the `FROM inserted` bit should have an equivalent `WHERE` clause to only pick those rows. I've updated the trigger in my solution below to not require the check at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize I gave you the conditional code for `IF EXISTS` but on further reflection I don't think it's necessary. Once you've calculated shape in the event that it's not already provided, you can still perform all of this work in a single statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.mytrigger
ON dbo.TBL_Locations
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid, loc_name, TOPO_NAME) 
  SELECT d.Shape, d.X_Coord, d.Y_Coord, d.objectid, d.loc_name, g.NAME
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      SHAPE = CASE WHEN SHAPE IS NOT NULL 
        THEN SHAPE ELSE Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('
          + CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' 
          + CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917) END,
      X_Coord = CASE WHEN SHAPE IS NULL THEN X_Coord ELSE SHAPE.STX END,
      Y_Coord = CASE WHEN SHAPE IS NULL THEN Y_Coord ELSE SHAPE.STY END,
      objectid, 
      loc_name
    FROM inserted
  ) AS d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QD24K_GRSM AS g
      ON g.Shape.STContains(d.Shape) = 1;
END
GO
```

Neither the existing solution nor this one handles odd cases, for example when shape and x/y coords are all populated, or when all three values are null, or when x_coord is populated by y is not (or vice-versa).

Comment: when shape is populated by the GIS, it trumps user xy, which is the desired behavior. thanks again! Now onto STDistance triggers....

Answer (score 1):

Why not include all of the script in the INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger?

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE SHAPE IS NOT NULL)     
  BEGIN         
    INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid, loc_name)             
    SELECT SHAPE, X_Coord = SHAPE.STX,Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY,objectid, loc_name            
    FROM inserted;    
  END
  ELSE     
  BEGIN 
    INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid,loc_name)             
    SELECT SHAPE=Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('+ CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917), X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid,loc_name
    FROM inserted;
  END

  set nocount on;

  INSERT INTO TBL_LOCATIONS (TOPO_NAME)        
  SELECT dbo.QD24K_GRSM.NAME        
  FROM   INSERTED I               
  LEFT JOIN dbo.QD24K_GRSM                 
  on QD24K_GRSM.Shape.STContains(I.SHAPE) = 1;
END
go
```

Comment: thought of that, and it returns `Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.`

Comment: In that case, maybe there's a problem with the last insert statement that has nothing to do with where it is placed in the trigger. If it worked, that statement would insert a second record into TBL_Locations with a value in only the TOPO_NAME field. Is that the intent?

Comment: No. Individually, each trigger works when the other is turned off. the intent is for the first trigger to populate the [shape] column if [X_Coord] and [Y_Coord] have been populated by the user OR populate the [X_Coord] and [Y_Coord] columns if the [Shape] column was populated. The second trigger is supposed to perform a spatial query and write the result (the name of the poly the point occurs in) to the [topo_name] column. This is all supposed to happen on one row. E.g. user enters new row, XY is calculated on that row, and the name of the topo is determined for that row.

Comment: the first trigger is deriving its values from the same row: if the user enters one column, the other is populated, and vice-versa. The second trigger derives its values from an entirely different table. perhaps where the problem is? When I separate the trigger into two triggers, it continues to fail.

Comment: "INSERT INTO TBL_LOCATIONS (TOPO_NAME)..." is always going to insert a new record into TBL_LOCATIONS. If you mean to update an existing record you'll have to use an UPDATE statement, which means you'll need some way of determining which record to update. Alternatively, if you can figure out the value for TOPO_NAME prior to the INSERT statement, you could include it in the parameter list.

Comment: the accepted answer works pretty fast on a 10000 record insert, about 2 minutes, using GUID primary key, with less than 10% fragmentation. Nice.